# How to add CORS (cross origin allow) to API Gateway authorized by Cognito userPool

Tags: typescript, cors, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I'm trying to add `defaultCorsPreflightOptions` in CDK to my `LambdaRestApi` instance which is configured to use COGNITO as authorizationType. The code block is as follows:

```js
 const restApi = new LambdaRestApi(this, 'MyServiceRestApi', {
      handler: serviceAPIGWLambdaHandler,
      domainName: {
        domainName: `service.${rootDomain}`,
        certificate: Certificate.fromCertificateArn(
          this,
          `explanation`,
          serviceDomainCertificate.certificateArn,
        ),
      },
      defaultCorsPreflightOptions: { allowOrigins: Cors.ALL_ORIGINS },
      proxy: true,
      endpointTypes: [EndpointType.EDGE],
      defaultMethodOptions: {
        authorizationType: AuthorizationType.COGNITO,
        authorizer,
        authorizationScopes: this.oauthScopes,
        methodResponses: [
          {
            statusCode: '200',
          },
        ],
      },
    });
```

The problem in here is that if I remove that `defaultCorsPreflightOptions` the CDK gets deployed successfully. But if I want to add cross-origin as above using `defaultCorsPreflightOptions` CDK would complain with the following error:

```bash
Invalid Method authorization type specified. Authorization Scopes are only valid
for COGNITO_USER_POOLS authorization type (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code
: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 033064c4-929b-4ab4-b7a9-08e35
2d0492b; Proxy: null)
```

**Is there any way that I can add CORS to the LambdaRestApi with COGNITO authorizer?**

Comment: You have both `authorizer` and `authorizationType: AuthorizationType.COGNITO` set at the same time. `authorizer` is only compatible with `AuthorizationType.CUSTOM` See the docs here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.MethodOptions.html

Comment: Removing authorizationType didn't help, but if I remove the OAuth scope. It works but I get authorization failed exception which is normal.

Comment: If youre using Cognito, you shouldnt have a separate authorizer at all. CUSTOM is required if you bring your own authorizer

Comment: It's quite weird cause it's working as it should just without the preflight options. 
I can authenticate and provide the relevant scope and call the API.